# Laggy gifs in html... sometimes

Tags: html, image, gif, lag, animated-gif

I have gifs that I am embedding into html via the `<img></img>` element. I have found that sometimes they load perfectly and look wonderful, but sometimes they are fairly laggy and slow. More interestingly, sometimes they will run wonderfully for some extended amount of time, and suddenly start running laggy and slow.

A solution to this would be great, but I am really more interested in WHY this happens to begin with. It seems like once everything is loaded properly, they should just continue to run properly.

Comment: Browser performance depends on many factors. There's no generic answer to this.

Comment: There is a lot of reasons effects image loading! Do you need to lazy load the image like this? https://storage.googleapis.com/web-dev-assets/native-lazy-loading/lazyload.mp4

Comment: This would most certainly help. I will look into implementing lazy loading, thanks for this!